# Linkedin v2 vector asset upload error 400

Tags: linkedin-api

Hello everyone who suffering from Microsoft LI v2 migration.

I have issue with UGC with vector asset (image), it's based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#upload-the-asset

I have uploadUrl from the first query, and when i perform second query it gives me error 400. 
When i try to debug and cURL it ([according to their example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#upload-the-asset)), the last log lines:

```
> Content-Length: 1636960
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine

* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Unexpected EOF
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Unexpected EOF
```

In the first query(`registerUpload`), I don't have desired headers from the first query:

```
-H "x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms"
-H "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id:e10ace24-blah-4977-bar-89foo193e2ab"
```

Anyone had any luck with vector asset upload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by adding `'Accept' => '*/*'`(i experimented without it and it did not worked) and set request to `multipart` (ruby `Faraday` gem)

Answer (score 1):

The vector asset documentation you referenced is specific to uploading video content to LinkedIn. You can view image share documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-an-image-share

From the documentation, you can register your upload:

`POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload`

```
{
"registerUploadRequest": {
    "recipes": [
        "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image"
    ],
    "owner": "urn:li:person:8675309",
    "serviceRelationships": [
        {
            "relationshipType": "OWNER",
            "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
        }
    ]
}
```

which returns the upload URL you can use to submit your image:

```
{
"value": {
    "uploadMechanism": {
        "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest": {
            "headers": {},
            "uploadUrl": "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJbrN86Zm265gAAAWemyz2pxPSgONtBiZdchrgG872QltnfYjnMdb2j3A&app=1953784&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2H-IhpbfXrRow1"
        }
    },
    "mediaArtifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:feedshare-uploadedImage)",
    "asset": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ"
}
```

}

Comment: UGC can be created with image too by setting `feedshare-image` in `registerUpload` and then `shareMediaCategory` to `IMAGE`.

Comment: Could you please curl example here. I am already completed till example shown above.