# LinkedIn Vector Asset API keeps returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: go, linkedin-api

I have the following method that "uploads" media to LinkedIn using the URL and Headers provided from the registerUpload request. I have been trying various different ways to try and get this to work without success. As is, this returns `400 Bad Request` response when I try to upload a single image. The documentation does not seem very helpful in this particular case. What am I doing wrong here?

```
func (li *LinkedIn) UploadMedia(URL string, Headers map[string]string, File string) (err error) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    file, err := os.Open(File)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fi, _ := file.Stat()

    request, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", URL, file)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    request.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+li.Token)
    request.Header.Set("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0")
    request.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
    if val, ok := Headers["media-type-family"]; ok && val == "STILLIMAGE" {
        request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    }
    for i, v := range Headers {
        request.Header.Set(i, v)
    }
    request.ContentLength = fi.Size()
    request.TransferEncoding = []string{"identity"}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if response.StatusCode != 200 && response.StatusCode != 201 {
        log.Println(File)
        log.Println(request)
        for name, values := range response.Header {
            // Loop over all values for the name.
            fmt.Println(name, "-", values)
        }
        dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequestOut(request, false)
        log.Println(string(dump))
        log.Println(request.ContentLength)
        log.Println(response.StatusCode)
        log.Println(response)
        responseBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        err = errors.New(string(responseBody))
    }
    return
}
```

Added `Accept` header after seeing this question: [Linkedin v2 vector asset upload error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042957/linkedin-v2-vector-asset-upload-error-400)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` and changed the request method from `PUT` to `POST` worked even though it says otherwise in their documents